# SQL backup file made with MSSMS is not working... on MSSMS (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I Generated an SQL File to backup a database using MSSMS:

1. Right click on database
2. Generate scripts
3. Marked "Schema and data" on "Types of data to script"

As a result I got a complete SQL that effectively seems to contain all the needed information to rebuild my db from scratch, data included.

To test it, I tried to run it locally, and found myself stuck because MSSMS is throwing errors on the SQL Script that it itself made.... I does not make any sense :(

Am I missing sth?:

This is the first lines of the sql file just as MSSMS made it:

[image: error]

Any ideas?

EDIT 1

This is the error I get after removing all "ALTER DATABASE" (I assumed those were the configuration specifications that were causing trouble)

[image]

It now says the tables are already created though they are not present in the database (it did create the database tough, It's a progress!)

Comment: This might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56281343/access-denied-create-database-localdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you are trying to execute contains elements that are not valid because the edition of SQL you are running locally is not the same as the edition of SQL used to generate the script.

In your case, the script was generated from azure SQL, but you are running it on sql server express edition (localdb)

Remove the azure SQL specific elements and it will work.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your help! Now I understand the problem origin. I tried deleting all "ALTER DATABASE" between the "CREATE DATABASE" and the first "CREATE TABLE" but I got another error, I will edit my question to add a new image. Could you please help me know what are azure SQL specific elements in order to delete them?

Comment: The errors you are now getting are not related to azure scripting. As the errors say, the tables have already been created. You can't create a table that already exists! :)
I notice that there is no `use mortuary_db` statement in your script. Are you sure your script is running in the right database? Also, it wasn't the `alter database` statements that were the problem originally. It was the `edition` and `service_objective` elements in the `create database` statement

Comment: Success! I created the db first and then executed a query inside of it! 
Also, I deleted all the "ALTER" because several of them where causing conflicts and I deleted edition and service_objective too. Many thanks allmhuran! Couldn't figure it out without your help!

Answer (score 1):

The default scripting option in SSMS object explorer is the same database engine type and edition as the source database. It seems the source database is Azure SQL Database based on the `CREATE DATABASE` syntax so the script will not run against a stand-alone instance like your LocalDB instance.

You can either modify the script or generate a new script appropriate for your target instance. To generate a script for SQL Express LocalDB, click on the Advanced button on the Set Scripting Options page of the Generate Scripts wizard. Select these options:

```
Script for the database engine edition: Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition

Script for the database engine type: Stand-alone instance
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your help! Now I understand the problem origin. Unfortunately I don't have access to the original database anymore, how can I modify the SQL I have to be able to run it locally? Sorry it might be obvious but it is the first time I do this.